# How to enter the name of a column as an input parameter in a MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a stored procedure but I am not getting a correct response, I think that by replacing 'user' in sum(user) they are not of the same type.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE mySProcedure(IN user VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
    DECLARE sum1 DECIMAL(10,2);

    SELECT SUM(user) INTO sum1 FROM MyTable;
    SELECT s1 ;
END$$
DELIMITER
```

How could I convert to column type name?, Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE mySProcedure(IN user VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
    DECLARE sum1 DECIMAL(10,2);
    SET @dynamic_sql = CONCAT('SELECT SUM(', user, ') INTO @sum1 FROM MyTable');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @dynamic_sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    SELECT @sum1 AS sum1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

We have done the following:

1. Dynamic SQL Construction.
2. Prepared Statement Execution.
3. Result Selection.

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad I was able to help.